# How do I create a view to list documents for a user basing visibility on 2 condition?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, users

I have a taxonomy called 'sub-agency' and all users have one or more sub-agency connected with him.
I have a content type called 'documents' which have a taxonomy term field [connected to sub-agency taxonomy] and a user reference field.

Now I want a view who displays documents shared with
**logged user sub-agency** OR **have him in user reference field**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your title and question body don't seem to relate to one another - could you clarify what you're actually asking? I see both "How can I check user access for a node?" and "How do I create a view to list documents for a user?". Which one do you need help with? How far have you got so far in trying yourself? What worked? What didn't? And so on

Comment: So, is the question how to use OR conditions in [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)?